# How can I ignore the delete keyword?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a array that contains command aliases and names, however when a name with `delete` exists, it sets the value to 0 in the final array

```
const commands = collection.reduce((all, command) => [...all, command.name, ...(command.aliases
        ? command.aliases.keys()
        : [])], []);
```

How can I ignore the delete keyword to get the word delete in the final output instead of 0?

Some sample output

```
Collection [Map] {
  'purge' => { name: 'purge',
    description: 'Delete multiple messages at a time (up to 99).',
    category: 'Admin',
    usage: '<amount>',
    examples: [ '5', '99' ],
    aliases: [ 'delete' ],
    args: true,
    guildOnly: true,
    execute: [Function: execute],
    default:
     { name: 'purge',
       description: 'Delete multiple messages at a time (up to 99).',
       category: 'Admin',
       usage: '<amount>',
       examples: [Array],
       aliases: [Array],
       args: true,
       guildOnly: true,
       execute: [Function: execute] } },
  'setjoin' => { name: 'setjoin',
    description:
     'Sets a message which will be sent when a new user joins the server.',
    category: 'Admin',
    usage: '<message>',
    examples:
     [ 'Welcome to the server {{member}}',
       'User {{tag}} joined the server' ],
    args: true,
    guildOnly: true,
    execute: [Function: execute],
    default:
     { name: 'setjoin',
       description:
        'Sets a message which will be sent when a new user joins the server.',
       category: 'Admin',
       usage: '<message>',
       examples: [Array],
       args: true,
       guildOnly: true,
       execute: [Function: execute] } },
```

Comment: Can you show an example of an input that includes the 'delete' keyword so we can see the issue?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Right sorry, here is the output of `collection`: https://hastebin.com/owacujilix.php as you can see, the alias for purge is delete

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "sample output". That code doesn't produce any output.

Comment: The sample output is the output of console.log(collection)

Comment: How is that useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command.aliases` is an array. For the `purge` command that array has one key (`0`) and one value (`'delete'`). So when you use `command.aliases.keys( )` you get the array's indices, not the value.

Just use the array itself (`command.aliases`) instead:

```
const commands = collection.reduce((all, command) => [...all, command.name, ...(command.aliases
        ? command.aliases
        : [])], []);
```

Note: This has nothing to do with the keyword `'delete'`. You would get the same behaviour for any aliases.

Comment: Thank you, this did the job

Comment: You're welcome @Daniell . In the future please try to either confirm an assumption before asking or leave the assumption out of the question. You said that it happens when the keyword 'delete' is used, but if you had tried with any other alias you would've seen the same behaviour. Believing it was related to 'delete' could've led me and other people trying help down the wrong path, and in general incorrect assumptions may make it less likely that your questions get answered.